# PHP SQL Substring and process values

Tags: php, mysql

I need some information out of the database for my Event Calander.

Example:

The date is stored as 2013-11-01 now I want to store the month (11) in an $month so I can compare it.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: why don't you explode() it ? http://codepad.org/WiJCJkd9

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
$date = '2013-11-01';

$month = date('m', strtotime($date));  // 11
```

**OR**

You can directly select month from database like..

```
SELECT MONTH( Date_field ) AS new_date
FROM table_name
WHERE `id` =1
```

Comment: I have tested the SELECT MONTH approach and it worked, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is using function `MONTH(date)` in SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT MONTH(date_field) FROM table WHERE 1=1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$value = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$month = is_array($value) ? $value[0] : "-1";
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an ideal solution.

Comment: You are welcome. As you noticed there are many solutions, choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$datestr = '2013-11-01';


$month = substr($datestr,5,2);

print_r($month);
```

the index of the month is 5 and we take 2 characters from 5. so we get 11.

Comment: I was already testing an substring method, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
<?php
$date= '2013-11-01';
$date_val=explode('-',$date);
echo $date_val[1];//11
```

Comment: Will look into the explode function since I did not know it, thank you for the help!